# Linq Query Message: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: linq

Following are the columns name and its data type:

```
TemplateName string
TaskName     string
AvgDays      string (but contains int values)
```

my LINQ query:

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
            group r by r.Field<string>("TemplateName") into templates
            let totalDays = templates.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("AvgDays"))
            from t in templates
            group t by new
            {
                TemplateName = templates.Key,
                TaskName = t.Field<string>("TaskName"),
                TotalDays = totalDays
            } into tasks
            select new
            {
                tasks.Key.TemplateName,
                tasks.Key.TaskName,
                AvgDays = tasks.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("AvgDays")),
                tasks.Key.TotalDays
            }).CopyToDataTable();
```

I am getting error after execution of query. Error is "Specified cast is not valid.".
Please let me know where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `Field<int>` causes the problem, because the field is not really an `int`. As you said before, it's a `string`.

Try following

```
AvgDays = tasks.Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>("AvgDays"))),
```

`Field<T>` does not perform some magic transformation between different types. It's implemented like that:

```
return (T)((object)value);
```

In practice there is a little bit more code, but logic is the same. It just tried to cast your value to desired type, and as you probably know, casting `string` to `int` does not work.